# I have a problem to add Field into Wordpress order view

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

how can i know which file into my wordpress project to modify to add a new field in the order view
[image: Commande]
i want to add Field "Timbre Fiscale" and after that i want to add 1000 to the total
Like this

---

### product : 30.000

### Timbre Fiscale : 1.000

### Sub total : 31.000

i'm trying to get a solution